# Firefox profile not loaded in Open Browser with Robot Framework SeleniumLibrary 4.0

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, firefox-profile

I have created a new profile for Firefox to be used with Robot Framework SeleniumLibrary. However the profile is not loaded using the following

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Keywords ***
Just testing
    Open Browser    about:blank    Firefox    ff_profile_dir=C:${/}Users${/}Administrator${/}AppData${/}Roaming${/}Mozilla${/}Firefox${/}Profiles${/}dev

*** Test Cases ***
Just testing
```

Which profile is used can be seen from page [about:profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTno7.png)

However, when checking about:profiles on a browser launched by webdriver, the profile is not marked as in use: [page about:profiles on a browser launched by Webdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRIH7.png)

Any thoughts why Firefox profile is not loaded? 
EDIT: How do I know for sure if the profile is loaded or not?

Looking at geckodriver log the directory seems to be totally different

`mozrunner::runner    INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\rust_mozprofile2iM6KC"`

The reason I have created separate profile is to bypass NTLM authentication using AutoAuth extension when launching automated tests suite.

SeleniumLibrary 4.0.0 
Robot Framework 3.1.2 (Python 3.7.4 on win32)
Firefox 69.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at my custom keyword to setup firefox profile:

```
from robot.api import logger
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

class SeleniumPyExtension:

    @staticmethod
    def setup_firefox_profile(download_dir):
        profile = FirefoxProfile()
        logger.info('Download dir is {}'.format(download_dir))
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        profile.set_preference(
            'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
            'image/jpeg;'\
            'application/vnd.ms-excel;'\
            'application/octet-stream;'\
            'application/pdf;'\
            'application/ogg;'\
            'audio/mpeg;'
        )
        profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
        profile.update_preferences()
        profile_dir = profile.profile_dir
        logger.info('Profile is located at {}'.format(profile_dir))
        return profile_dir
```

and checked what it creates and it occurred that it creates directory with only `user.js` with bunch of `user_pref(...)` as described [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file).